# Android SurfaceView / MultiThreading messing up, Thread stuck in "signal catcher loop"

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I've been working on a sort of a game engine for Android but I have some serious stability issues.

I use a `SurfaceView` with an implemented `Runnable` for Multithreading, to get some work of my main / UI thread. The simplified version of this class is shown below:

```
private class MenuView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable
{
    Thread T = null;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    Canvas c;
    boolean run;

    public MenuView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        holder = getHolder();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(run)
        {
            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid())
            {
                continue;
            }
            c = holder.lockCanvas();

    //Doing updates and drawing stuff

            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
    }


    public void pause()
    {
        run = false;
        try
        {
            T.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            Log.e("Error:", "joining thread failed!");
        }
    }

    public void resume()
    {
        run = true;
        T = new Thread(this);
        T.start();
    }

    //bunch of helper methods with no effect on this problem :(

}
```

So as you can see, my "Worker" thread is caught in an infinite while loop that is controlled by the "run" boolean, and this boolean is set using pause() and resume() methods called in onPause() and onResume() methods of my activity as shown here:

```
MenuView menuV;
Random Rand = new Random();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Screen = getRealScreenSize(getApplicationContext());
    menuV = new MenuView(this);
    menuV.setOnTouchListener(this);
    logoV = new LogoView(this);
    setContentView(logoV);                          Log.d("APP", "SET LOGO VIEW");
//^ This is my splash screen, again irrelevant to the issue, after few seconds of running, this view calls the resume() of my SurfaceView and sets it as the contentView.
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("APP", "ON PAUSE");
    menuV.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

//^hides the goddamn navigation bar...

    Log.d("APP", "ON RESUME");
    menuV.resume();
}

    @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        Log.d("APP", "ON TOUCH DOWN");
        for(int i = 0; i < menuV.button.length ; i++)
        {
            if(menuV.button[i].active)
            {
                if(event.getX() > menuV.button[i].pos.left && event.getX() < menuV.button[i].pos.right && event.getY() > menuV.button[i].pos.top && event.getY() < menuV.button[i].pos.bottom)
                {
                    menuV.button[i].pressed = true;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        Log.d("APP", "ON TOUCH UP");
        for(int i = 0; i < menuV.button.length ; i++)
        {
            menuV.button[i].pressed = false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

**So my touch event is handled by the UI thread, but it's accesing info that the worker thread is constantly using, the same thing happens in onPause() and onResume(), the UI thread is changing the "run" boolean which is always used by the worker thread, I'm saying this because it seems that the ANRs are happening when touching the screen and when power-off-ing and power-on-ing the phone. Rendering doesn't stop, it seems that the worker thread is just fine but the UI thread messes up badly, it stops responding and this line shows on my Android Monitor:**

Thread[2,tid=18257,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x558cbf1310,peer=0x12c470a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3

Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

**Please let me know if there is any further useful information - I will EDIT in anything you point out as important after this line, Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

Try marking `run` variable as volatile:

```
volatile boolean run;
```

Maybe you have caching-related problem.

Comment: I tried that, nothing, but than do I need to make all the Button data accessed in onTouch() volatile as well? Or some type of syncing maybe?

Comment: onTouch() should be running on the main thread, you can check it. You haven't provided any code for onTouch in question though.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it, now it's the entire onTouch() method :)

Comment: Another source of the problems could be the recreation of SurfaceHolder. Try to add SurfaceHolder callbacks to your surface to reassign holder variable on SurfaceHolder recreations. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html

Comment: But the rendering never stops, even when the ANR happens, all the animations, calculations and rendering that the worker thread does still goes on while Android tells me the app is not responding, only touch stops  working? Very strange...

Comment: Did you try to use debugger? :)

Comment: Ummm you mean click "Debug", get an app running on my device and look on the Android monitor for outputs.....or you mean something more hi-tech....i'm a noob :/

Comment: Will do, also can you please tell me how do I retrieve the traces.txt, i know I'm supposed to type some "adb retrieve ......." line somewhere, but... I don't know where :( That file should help me people say.